# How to truly disable modules in magento2

Tags: magento2, module

I have a module that has errors when compiling.

I am disabling it via cli: `magento module:disable Aheadworks_Layerednav`.

Then `magento module:status` shows the module as disabled. Cleared cache, removed everything from var folder.

But then when I run `magento setup:di:compile` I get 
Errors during compilation:

```
    Aheadworks\Layerednav\Block\Navigation
        Incorrect dependency in class Aheadworks\Layerednav\Block\Navigation in /data/web/public/app/code/Aheadworks/Layerednav/Block/Navigation.php
\Magento\Store\Model\StoreManagerInterface already exists in context object
```

My expectation was that disabled modules aren't compiled.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

@claudiu Creanga it looks like if you rename or remove your registration.php that when you run the `module:status` command after running `module:disable Your_Module`, the module doesn't show up in the "List of disabled modules". Then if you run `setup:di:compile` you won't see any errors, if there are any, for that module.

**UPDATE**: I was focusing on the di compilation and not focusing on the error message you shared. Your solution is here: http://magento-quickies.alanstorm.com/post/138686669515/quick-note-on-already-exists-in-context-object . Your problem doesn't have anything to do with a module not being disabled. It's a matter of doubly injecting an interface.

1. Looks like you'll want to go to your `/data/web/public/app/code/Aheadworks/Layerednav/Block/Navigation.php` class
2. Look for the `StoreManagerInterface` being passed as an argument to your constructor and remove that and the comma from the line above (if there is one)
3. Then, in the body of the constructor, there will probably be something like `$this->_storeManager = $storeManager` or `$this->_storeManagerInterface = $storeManagerInterface` (I don't have the extension, so I can't give you an exact answer; But if you'd like to post your code I can show you exactly what to change); Make sure you're assigning `$this->_storeManager = $context->getStoreManager()` instead of an instance of the `StoreManagerInterface`

If you check `Magento\Framework\View\Element\Template\Context` class you'll see the `getStoreManager()` method, which returns an instance of `\Magento\Store\Model\StoreManagerInterface`, therefore the error you're seeing is Magento telling you that this StoreManagerInterface is already available, so no need to inject it into the Navigation block's constructor.

One of the things that intrigued me from Alan's article, was that these errors aren't shown in Developer mode, only when we explicitly run the `setup:di:compile` command.

I hope this helps.

Comment: It also seems that if you've disabled the modules, but you left the modules in your code base, under code/Vendor/ModuleA, and you run any of the di compilation commands, that M2 will still try to compile the di for those modules...so it appears you'd have to use `setup:di:compile-multi-tenant --exlude-pattern` or `setup:di:compile --exlude-pattern` in order to tell the di compilation command to ignore your module directories which have been disabled.

Comment: yes, cleared all folders in var. It seems that there is no parameter exlude-pattern. using 2.0.7

Comment: @ClaudiuCreanga it appears the exclude pattern is not present in the `setup:di:compile`, but is still present in the `setup:di:compile-multi-tenant` command. I just tested it out on 2.0.7

Comment: @ClaudiuCreanga my mistake, this isn't available for `setup:di:compile` for 2.0.6 and 2.0.7.

Comment: We removed the multi-tenant compiler some time back.

Comment: @SteveJohnson do you mean that the `--exclude-pattern` parameter was removed from multi-tenant compiler some time back, as the multi-tenant command is still present in the CLI as of 2.0.7?

Comment: @ClaudiuCreanga not a problem. Happy sailing!

Comment: @ryanF Could be faulty memory. Maybe `setup:di:compile-multi-tenant` isn't being removed until 2.1 but I'm pretty sure the entire command is going away.

Comment: @SteveJohnson Thank you for the clarification!